# Using While Loop Through Telegram Arrays

Tags: php, bots, telegram

How can I use a while loop for 'media' section arrays to send multiple images which is based on my host.

```
$postContent = [
    'chat_id' => $GLOBALS['chatId'],
    'media' => json_encode([
        ['type' => 'photo', 'media' => 'attach://file1.png' ], // Use while loop instead
    ]),
    'file1.png' => new CURLFile(realpath($filePath1)), // Use while loop instead
];
post($url, $postContent);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I just started while loop at the beginning and replaced variables instead of values. But it sends images one after one, not together.
 code: while ($q = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { $post_params = [ 'chat_id' => $GLOBALS['chat_id'], 'media' => json_encode([ ['type' => 'photo', 'media' => 'attach://file1.png', 'caption' => 'Hello'], ]), 'file1.png' => new \CURLFile(DIR . '/jpg1.png'), ]; } send_reply($url, $post_params);